# Background color need to be Transparent for Button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

I have a button, i don't want other to the shape of button; i want them to see only the Text of button, So i made button background color "#FFFFFF"(full white) and also made background of layout "#FFFFFF"(fullwhite)..but i could still see the button shape when install app in phone;

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/toggle"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="100dp"           
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOff="Off"
        android:textOn="On"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```

what should i do..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
android:color="#FFFFFF"    
android:alpha="1"
```

Or if that doesn't work, try this:

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: i got light pink button background which is clearly visible...i want to hide shape of button (which means i need to implement 100% transparent button background).. :(

Comment: how to get 100% transparent background..??

Comment: I edited my answer, this should work because your setting the color to white and you have full transparency. Let me know if anything goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: thanks for support..i can't vote but i vl accept all u tried to help me..

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background color to transparent:

```
android:background="#00000000"
```

Or

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```